# X-axis labels are overlapped in LightningChart js

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

[image: Overlapping axis labels]
Please see attached screenshot how labels are overlapped.

```js
const lsjs = this.libraryInstance;
      // Create a new axis so as to show date on X axis
      const xAxis = this.chartInstance.addAxisX().setTickStrategy(lsjs.AxisTickStrategies.DateTime,
         (tickStrategy) => tickStrategy
            // This will format a data-point with value 0 as current Date and Time.
            .setDateOrigin(new Date(dateOrigin))
            .setFormattingDay(
            { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
            { day: '2-digit' },
            { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
          .setMinorTickStyle(undefined)
          .setGreatTickStyle(this.libraryInstance.emptyTick))
          .setAnimationZoom(undefined)
          .setChartInteractionZoomByWheel(false)
          .setAnimationScroll(undefined);
```

Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a bug in how we are handling the axis labels. We hope to be able to resolve this in a future release.

Comment: Hi, is this bug fixed yet

Comment: @Snekw is this bug fixed in new release

Comment: It hasn't been fixed yet. We have it marked as high priority bug to be fixed in next release coming this spring.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in LightningChart JS v3.0.0. You can download the new version from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@arction/lcjs).